# Testcafe: Is there a way that a Role can detect an expired session?

Tags: testcafe

we have the following issue:

We're testing an application that terminates all the current sessions from all active devices for a given user once they log out. This results in the `AuthenticatedUser` role getting logged out with no way to automatically log back in, and all subsequent tests failing after a logout.

Is there a way that the Role can be re-initialized or somehow forced to redo the login steps after a session expires? I tried manually forcing a login inside `test.after` after the a logout step but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-initialize `Role` using only a private API. See the example in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5566#issuecomment-699931257).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that approach and see how it goes.